# Jmeter validating response

Tags: jmeter

In the below code  ‘ScenarioName’ represents the test case name and ‘DeviceID’ as input parameter, while fetching response. Now I need to crosscheck each field of the response data with the field that are given in the input csv. So if it gets matched then only we will say the result is pass or else fail..

Code as of now:(It just hit the service and write the response in result CSV. But before writing it in resultant CSV, we need to validate whether all the field in the response are gets matched corresponding to the value for that particular scenario specified in the input CSV, only then we would come to a conclusion. whether the test case is pass or fail. )

Beanshell post processor code:

```
scenario = vars.get("ScenarioName");
deviceid = vars.get("DeviceID");
eventname = vars.get("C_EventName");
eventtype = vars.get("C_EventType");
areaName = vars.get("C_AreaName");

n = vars.get("counter");

filename = "C:\\RestService\\"+ n +".csv";

f = new FileOutputStream(filename, true); 

p = new PrintStream(f); 

this.interpreter.setOut(p); 

print( scenario + ", " + etrTimestamp + ", " + eventname + ", " + eventtype + ", " + areaName + ", " + areaType  + ", " + additionalInfo  + ", " + resultStatusCode + ", " + resultStatusMessage);

f.close();
```

**Now My input file:**

```
ScenarioName   DeviceID  Execution

Validate event   52226406   Yes   

invalid ID       11501233   Yes
```

But input file should be:

```
ScenarioName       DeviceID     Execution   EVENTNAME     REsultCODE  

Validate event      52226406      Yes       Hurricane         200    

invalid ID          11501233      Yes        Tornado          404
```

Now my Output is:

```
ScenarioName      DeviceID     Execution    EVENTNAME      REsultCODE  

Validate event    52226406       Yes        Hurricane          200    

invalid ID        11501233       Yes        Tsunami            404
```

But It should be:

```
ScenarioName       DeviceID           EVENTNAME      REsultCODE    Result

Validate event     52226406           Hurricane       Event        Pass     

invalid ID         11501233           Tsunami         404          Fail
```

So let’s say for DeviceID  52226406 if we are validating the test case, then we would say the result as pass only if all the fields exactly match with data present in the input csv….But For DeviceID 11501233   Event type should be Tornado But in response we are getting as Tsunami so it should fail(After we match with the input CSV)
What should my code and how?

Answer (score 0):

1. Be aware that [starting from JMeter 3.1 it is strongly recommended to use JSR223 Test Elements and Groovy language](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting) for scripting so consider migrating to [JSR223 Assertion](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeter-assertions-3-easy-steps) and Groovy language on next available opportunity.
2. Your requirement can be accomplished without any scripting, like:

   - You already have expected variable in the CSV file which can be extracted using [CSV Data Set Config](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config)
   - You can extract actual variables from the response using suitable [JMeter PostProcessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#postprocessors), given you have `Rest` in your code my expectation is that it would be [JSON Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_Extractor)
   - 2 variables can be compared using [Response Assertion](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Response_Assertion) like:

     [image: JMeter Response Assertion Compare 2 Variables]
3. If you need to store the actual data for any reason you can use [Sample Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/listeners.html#sample_variables) property or [Flexible File Writer](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/FlexibleFileWriter/)

Comment: In beanshellpostprocessor  facing error:
if((vars.get("C_EventName").equals("${EventName}"))&& (vars.get("C_AreaName").equals("${AreaName}")) && (vars.get("C_resultStatusMessage").equals("${ResultStatusMessage}")) ;
{IsSuccess = true;
n = vars.get("counter");
fname = "C:\\RestService\\Results\\"+ n +".csv";
f = new FileOutputStream(fname, true); 
p = new PrintStream(f); 
this.interpreter.setOut(p); 
print( scenario + ", " + etrTimestamp + ", " + eventname + ",  " + areaName + ",  " + resultStatusCode + ", " + resultStatusMessage);
f.close();
}else{IsSuccess = false;
}

Comment: just before writing if I go for validation in bean shell postprocessor. getting error